# c# attempt to write blob data to db fails

Tags: c#, character-encoding, ssis, stream, blob

How can I read a text file contents and write them to a varchar(max) column using SSIS?

I am using SSIS to read some files (not flat files or I would just use a flat file source). The structure is similar to X12.
the script source component is suposed to read the file, extract records based on the format and pass them to a transform script component and then onto an oledb destination

In the source script component using the following code results in what I think are encoding issues and unintelligible data written to the db

```
private MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}


using (MemoryStream s = GenerateStreamFromString(stringfromfile))
   { 
     Output0Buffer.Value.AddBlobData(s.ToArray()); 
   }
```

This approach works when I read data from a db varchar(max) column into a DT_TEXT SSIS type, pass it to a script transform and then write it back to the same column; It breaks when I read from file and convert the string to byte arrays

Comment: You are attempting to encode a string as binary and then store to a table, yeah?

Comment: Yes eventually writing to a db varchar(max) column. length of my data can get very long. had to massage it this way so ssis would accept the data in a DT_TEXT /text stream column that ends up being mapped to thre varchar(max) in the db